# How to do something if localstorage key starts with a certain string?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to check if localstorage item key that (starts with a certain string) exists then fire a code.

An example that works if I know the exact key

```
if (localStorage.getItem('mykey') !== null) {
    document.querySelector("#button").textContent="hello";
}
```

So how can i check if the local storage has a key that starts with "mykey" and if yes fire a code? I think i can do this with a filter as i checked the documentation but was not really able to figure out how to put it in code

Comment: As far as I know you can't, but you can loop the existing keys (for instance, using `string.includes()`), as the duplicate explains.

Comment: Try using `Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => key.startsWith('string'))` to get the key.

Comment: Perfect that works, i was actually trying like this to filter `Object.entries(localStorage).filter(([key]) => key.startsWith('string'));`